# Firebase Chat Recycler View Left and Right View Not Working Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I want the chat message Align like this when I send message I want them on the right when I receive I want them on left like this in the image

[image]

but it looks like this even though I set to two different layouts for in and out but it appears in the same way

[image]

In ChatRoomActvity getItemViewType(int position) always return as MESSAGE_IN_VIEW_TYPE;

What am I missing here?

**ChatRoomActvity.java**

```
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private FirebaseUser mFirebaseUser;
private DatabaseReference mFirebaseDatabaseReference;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage, MessageViewHolder>
        mFirebaseAdapter;
public static final String MESSAGES_CHILD = "messages";
public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
private static final String TAG = "ChatRoomAct";
private static final int REQUEST_IMAGE = 2;
private static final String LOADING_IMAGE_URL = "https://www.google.com/images/spin-32.gif";


private FloatingActionButton mSendButton;
private RecyclerView mMessageRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private EditText mMessageEditText;
private ImageView mAddMessageImageView;
private String mUsername;
private String mPhotoUrl;
private String mUserid;
private String mSenderUid;

//Emoji Function
private ImageView emojiButton;
private EmojiPopup emojiPopup;
private ViewGroup rootView;
private EmojiEditText editText;



private final int MESSAGE_IN_VIEW_TYPE  = 1;
private final int MESSAGE_OUT_VIEW_TYPE = 2;

public static class MessageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


    TextView mTime;
    CircleImageView imgProfile;


    TextView messageTextView;
    ImageView messageImageView;
    TextView messengerTextView;
    CircleImageView messengerImageView;
    TextView mLikesCount;
    ImageView imgDropdown, imgLikes;


    public MessageViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);

        messengerTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
        messageTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
        mTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
        messengerImageView = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgDps);
        imgLikes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgLikes);
        mLikesCount = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_Likes);





    }
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat_room_actvity);


    // Initialize ProgressBar and RecyclerView.
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loader);
    mMessageRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ChatRoomActvity.this);
    mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mMessageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);



    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

    mUserid = mFirebaseUser.getUid();

    mUsername = ANONYMOUS;
    if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
        finish();
        return;
    } else {
        mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
        if (mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
            mPhotoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        }
    }

    displaychatmessages();
}


public void displaychatmessages() {


    mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage> parser = new SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage>() {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public FriendlyMessage parseSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = snapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage.class);
            if (friendlyMessage != null) {
                friendlyMessage.setId(snapshot.getKey());
            }
            return friendlyMessage;
        }

    };
    DatabaseReference messagesRef = mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD);
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<FriendlyMessage> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FriendlyMessage>()
                    .setQuery(messagesRef, parser)
                    .build();
    mFirebaseAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage, MessageViewHolder>(options) {



        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            if(getItem(position).getId().equals(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()))
            {
                return MESSAGE_OUT_VIEW_TYPE;
            } else {
                return MESSAGE_IN_VIEW_TYPE;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(MessageViewHolder viewHolder, int position, FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage) {

            mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
            if (friendlyMessage.getText() != null) {
                viewHolder.messageTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getText());
                viewHolder.messageTextView.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
                viewHolder.mTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd MMM  (h:mm a)", friendlyMessage.getMessageTime()));
                viewHolder.mLikesCount.setText(String.valueOf(friendlyMessage.getMessageLikesCount()));
                if (friendlyMessage.getMessageLikes() != null) {
                    if (friendlyMessage.getMessageLikes().containsValue(mUserid)) {
                        viewHolder.imgLikes.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_heart);
                    } else {
                        viewHolder.imgLikes.setImageResource(R.drawable.chat_heart);
                    }
                }

            }

            viewHolder.messengerTextView.setText(friendlyMessage.getName());
            if (friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl() == null) {
                viewHolder.messengerImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(ChatRoomActvity.this,
                        R.drawable.profile));
            } else {
                Glide.with(ChatRoomActvity.this)
                        .load(friendlyMessage.getPhotoUrl())
                        .into(viewHolder.messengerImageView);
            }

        }



        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MessageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = null;
            if(i==MESSAGE_IN_VIEW_TYPE){
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.message_in, viewGroup, false);
            }
            else if(i==MESSAGE_OUT_VIEW_TYPE){
                view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.message_out, viewGroup, false);
            }
            return new MessageViewHolder(view);

        }

    };
    mFirebaseAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
            int friendlyMessageCount = mFirebaseAdapter.getItemCount();
            int lastVisiblePosition =
                    mLinearLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
            // If the recycler view is initially being loaded or the
            // user is at the bottom of the list, scroll to the bottom
            // of the list to show the newly added message.
            if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                    (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) &&
                            lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                mMessageRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
            }
        }
    });

    mMessageRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseAdapter);

    mMessageEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
    mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
            } else {
                mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }

    });

    mSendButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = new
                    FriendlyMessage(mUserid,mMessageEditText.getText().toString(),null,
                    mUsername,
                    mPhotoUrl,
                    null /* no image */);
            mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD)
                    .push().setValue(friendlyMessage);
            mMessageEditText.setText("");
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mFirebaseAdapter.startListening();

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mFirebaseAdapter.stopListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
 super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
super.onBackPressed();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: requestCode=" + requestCode + ", resultCode=" + resultCode);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                final Uri uri = data.getData();
                Log.d(TAG, "Uri: " + uri.toString());

                FriendlyMessage tempMessage = new FriendlyMessage(null,null,null,mUsername, mPhotoUrl,
                        LOADING_IMAGE_URL);
                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).push()
                        .setValue(tempMessage, new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(DatabaseError databaseError,
                                                   DatabaseReference databaseReference) {
                                if (databaseError == null) {
                                    String key = databaseReference.getKey();
                                    StorageReference storageReference =
                                            FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
                                                    .getReference(mFirebaseUser.getUid())
                                                    .child(key)
                                                    .child(uri.getLastPathSegment());

                                    putImageInStorage(storageReference, uri, key);
                                } else {
                                    Log.w(TAG, "Unable to write message to database.",
                                            databaseError.toException());
                                }
                            }

                            private void putImageInStorage(StorageReference storageReference, Uri uri, String key) {
                                storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnCompleteListener(ChatRoomActvity.this,
                                        new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl()
                                                            .addOnCompleteListener(ChatRoomActvity.this,
                                                                    new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                                                        @Override
                                                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                                                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                                                FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage =
                                                                                        new FriendlyMessage(null,null,null, mUsername, mPhotoUrl,
                                                                                                task.getResult().toString());
                                                                                mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child(MESSAGES_CHILD).child(key)
                                                                                        .setValue(friendlyMessage);
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    });
                                                } else {
                                                    Log.w(TAG, "Image upload task was not successful.",
                                                            task.getException());
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**FriendlyMessage.java**

```
public class FriendlyMessage {

private String id;
private String text;
private String name;
private String photoUrl;
private String imageUrl;
private long messageTime;
private long  messageLikesCount;
private Map<String, Boolean> messageLikes = new HashMap<>();

public FriendlyMessage(){}

public FriendlyMessage(String id,String text,String name, String photoUrl, String imageUrl) {
    this.id = id;
    this.text = text;
    this.name = name;
    messageTime = new Date().getTime();
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    this.messageLikesCount = messageLikesCount;
    this.messageLikes= messageLikes;

}


public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPhotoUrl() {
    return photoUrl;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setPhotoUrl(String photoUrl) {
    this.photoUrl = photoUrl;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return imageUrl;
}

public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
    this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
}

public long getMessageTime() {
    return messageTime;
}

public void setMessageTime(long messageTime) {
    this.messageTime = messageTime;
}

public long getMessageLikesCount() {
    return messageLikesCount;
}

public void setMessageLikesCount(long messageLikesCount) {
    this.messageLikesCount = messageLikesCount;
}

public Map<String, Boolean> getMessageLikes() {
    return messageLikes;
}

public void setMessageLikes(Map<String, Boolean> messageLikes) {
    this.messageLikes = messageLikes;
}
```

}

Comment: you haven't added the pictures

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **500** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: @MehranBehbahani thanks for the reply I added the image

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks for the tip sir I try to edit the question as MCVE

Comment: can you please share the XML files for the two different layouts you are using?

Comment: @MehranBehbahani Thanks for the reply Message out https://pastebin.com/Rgs7YKZj
Message In https://pastebin.com/mvHnQXtV

Comment: this link is broken. add it to your question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {

            FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = getItem(position);
            
            boolean user = (friendlyMessage.getUserid().equals(mUserid));

            if(user)
            {
                return MESSAGE_OUT_VIEW_TYPE;
            } else {
                return MESSAGE_IN_VIEW_TYPE;
            }
        }
```

I use boolean

Comment: How can I show the date view for messages for grouping the date

Answer (score 0):

I can't without the images (for any reason, they are not in the post) but from what I see,

```
getItem(position).getId().equals(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
```

and

```
FriendlyMessage.getId()
```

I'd say you're not taking the sender into account. ID is conventionally used as a message number, they usually do not point to a uid. Besides, your class already has a field called `senderUid`, so you should compare against that instead of `id`.

Optionally, try to log the line before the condition.

Comment: Z  Khan Thanks for the reply I add as you say but it remains the same can you be more specific I don't use sender id because it shows null value is any way to solve this

mUserid = mFirebaseUser.getUid();

  @Override
            public int getItemViewType(int position) {
                if(getItem(position).getId().equals(mUserid))
                {
                    return MESSAGE_OUT_VIEW_TYPE;
                } else {
                    return MESSAGE_IN_VIEW_TYPE;
                }
            }

Comment: My understanding is you need two IDs. either `id` and `senderUid`, or `senderUid` and `receiverUid`. Because you need an extra field to determine who sent the message. In your class, I assume it would be `senderUid`, that's why I suggested the aforementioned. Just to clarify, what do you use the `id` field for?